# Simon the leper and Simon the Pharisee are one person and Mary of Bethany is not the woman of ill-repute with alabaster jar

Tags: hebrew, john, luke, contradiction

The Hebrew Roots Bible denotes Simon in these events of the women anointing Jesus as Simon the potter. In Aramaic the name Simon is Shimeon for the Pharisee and for the potter. Is it possible that years after Jesus' death, Simon the Pharisee had become a potter? The writers (Matt, Mark and John) were then identifying him as the person he had become. Luke denotes him as a Pharisee because in the story Simon's words and actions and Jesus' rebuke hinge on his identity as a Pharisee. Simon could have renounced his office as Pharisee for the life of a potter after the resurrection of Jesus. This renunciation would make sense if in fact he is related to Lazarus, Mary, and Martha. He may have become a potter as the rebuked position of Pharisee is no longer desirable to a changed man, converted as a disciple. This profession would also help him maintain a low profile after Jesus' crucifixion? Also Mary of Bethany anoints Jesus 6 days before Passover and the woman of ill-repute anoints 2 days before. Alabaster is only listed as a descriptor where the woman of ill-repute is anointing. Is is possible the woman of ill-repute heard of Mary's anointing and wanted to do the same?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour - link below.

Comment: Problem here is that we are not told so the answer to this is speculative.

Comment: If Mark used a historical present in Mark 14:3, then he would have referenced in lively narration an event that happened in time past, not something that was happening right then. This would make it not necessary to reckon two different women with two different oil boxes of the same price in two different situations only days apart.

Comment: I agree that there are two accounts of two incidents and that it is impossible to say that they are identical. The details are such that one cannot identify the woman who was called a sinner. I totally agree. Up-voted +1.

Comment: I'd be very wary of the 'Hebrew Roots' movement in general, for reasons just like this - there's a tremendous amount of speculation in trying to convert all the Greek texts back into Hebrew equivalents. Many then begin throwing out Paul's letters or other early church history witnesses on the merits of being too 'Greek'. Best to take a lot of it with a pinch of salt.